# Создание CyanogenMod из похожих моделей

Tags: android

У меня Samsung G361H. Для этого телефона нет CyanogenMod. По этому я бы хотел создать свой. Но у меня компьютер с оперативной памятью 2 Гб и архитектурой х32. Это значит что я не могу компилировать из исходников. Могу ли я сделать вот это:

1. Скачать CyanogenMod для телефона с похожими характеристиками.
2. Сделать полный дамп стоковой прошивки на телефоне.
3. Копировать важные вещи такие как ядро и тд. из стока в CyanogenMod.
4. Полученный архив прошить на телефон

Comment: вы спрашиваете не в том месте.

Comment: Для начала компьютер обновить, если позволяют средства. По нынешним временам для разработки минимум нужно иметь i3/8GB RAM/128GB SSD. Иначе это будет не разработка, а мучение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему не сможете скомпилировать? В одно время я компилировал ядро на ПК  с Xubuntu с x86 и всего 1Гб ОЗУ, правда по времени выходило долго. Если говорить о портировании прошивки с одного устройства на другое, то Ваша последовательность верна, лишь нужно подобрать максимально идентичный "донор", выбрать " донорскую" версию Android такую же, что у стока, иметь при себе утилиты для распаковки файлов ядер и обеих прошивок, базовое понимание smali (ну, это приходит во время процесса), а также программу, в которой можно отслеживать logcat. Последнее - необходимая вещь, так как  исправление ошибок при портировании прошивки подразумевает и "ковыряние" в ядре, фреймворке, и подстановку файлов со стока. Советую для начала попробовать портировать MIUI, на одном популярном форуме расписан процесс портирования очень доступно.
В ряде проблем лучше на всякий случай иметь при себе JTAG, так как "окирпичить" телефон чужими радиомодулями, и, бывает, ядрами - дело простое.
Только помните, что даже самый лучший порт прошивки будет проигрывать прошивке, собранной с исходников.
Кстати о исходниках: можете найти исходные коды (по всей видимости ядер) для G361H здесь: http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=search&searchValue=G361H

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит архитектура процессора и ОЗУ влияют только на время сборки? Обязательно постараюсь следовать вашему совету

Comment: Действительно, иначе прошивка будет компилироваться очень и очень долго.